# How to add a library into Processing from Eclipse platform?

Tags: eclipse, processing

I installed the Processing plugin for Eclipse. it works fine. But then i copied the folder gifAnimation into `C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\processing.plugin.core_0.2.5.1\Resources\libraries`. All the other libraries are there.

but `"import gifAmination.*;"` does not work.

and gives the following error.

Library import "gifAnimation" could not be found. Check the library folder in your sketchbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I used Processing in Eclipse, but I think you need to add libraries explicitly to the build path.  There is a [tutorial here](http://creativecoding.org/en/beyond/p5/eclipse_as_editor#using_opengl_other_libraries) which will walk you through the whole process of getting Eclipse working with Processing, including adding extra libraries. The main thing you need to do is browse to your added libraries, and use Eclipse's 'Add to Build Path" menu option.